# Backtracking for Knapsack

Tags: algorithm, tree, knapsack-problem, bounds

I need to do use backtracking to solve a Knapsack problem. This is an example of what I might have to do for my problem. My question is, how do I know the bounds? I understand that the bound for the root node is $115 because it is the sum of all values. But what I don't understand is how the right child of the root has a bound of $82.

I found this text explaining what it means, but I am still confused:

```
For a maximization problem the bound is an upper bound, 
    – the largest possible solution that can be achieved by 
      expanding the node is less or equal to the upper bound
```

[image]

Comment: Please provide all items and weight limit you are talking about. The picture shows 4 items with total value of $40+$30+$50+$10=$130. That's obviously not your mentioned $115.

Answer (score 0):

I have figured it out:

bound = profit  +  p1 + p2 + (C - 7 ) * p3 / w3 = $0 + $40 + $30 + (16 -7) X $50/10 = $115